# Receiving notifications from Slack Direct messages

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm building a simple slack bot and can currently send private messages as well as checking for the last 10 messages received within this one-to-one channel.

Is there a way of getting a POST notification to my webservice whenever the user replies, instead of having to poll and continuously check messages on that one-to-one channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots generally work by connecting to the [real-time messaging API](https://api.slack.com/rtm), a WebSocket-based API that sends you events as they happen. Specifically, you should see a [`message`](https://api.slack.com/events/message) event sent to you every time a message visible to your bot is sent.

To answer your question, there's no way to get an HTTP POST sent to you instead; you'll need to connect to the RTM API and listen for events that way.

Comment: It's worth noting that **in the future**, you will be able to subscribe to certain events and register a webhook. So there might not be a need to use the RTM API. This is a near term feature on their [platform roadmap](https://trello.com/c/OoyM032q/8-events-api)

Answer (score 1):

Now you can make use of Slack events to receive notifications.

In the give use-case, 'Message' event can be used to capture message received and process accordingly.

https://api.slack.com/events/message